# @autoreleasepool does not seem to drain pool

Tags: ios, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I am having memory issues in a larger application. I've simplified it to the code below. If I let the application run to completion, the memory drains, and therefore I don't have a true memory leak.

However, as it's running, each call to customLog: accumulates memory and the memory does not drain. So I added an @autoreleasepool block wrapping the call to log: and it still does not seem to drain. Is it possible I am not using @autoreleasepool correctly?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        [Logger customLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<100000000; i++) {
        NSLog(@"X%i", i);
    }
}
```

Logger class:

```
- (void)customLog:(NSString *)logString
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [self log:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@:%d\t\t%s\t\%@", [[NSDate  date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%F" timeZone:nil locale:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]], [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, logString]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Use alloc init objects only in the autoreleasepool block. Do not use any class factory methods as those objects have different lifecycle.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but you are creating and draining 100000 separate autorelease pools in your first `for` loop. Perhaps it doesn't play well with your app design, but it would seem to make more sense to wrap **the whole `for` loop in one autorelease pool**? Oh, and also +1 for Edward's comment regarding factory methods (although I can't recall right now the exact difference between alloc and factory since ARC).

Comment: @EdwardL. The point of `@autoreleasepool` is to clean up autoreleased objects created inside it. Using only `alloc/init` inside an autorelease pool precludes the need for the autorelease pool.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm just pointing out the fact that the two calls are not one and the same. In alloc init, the creating client owns the created object, whereas in factory method, the client does not own the object and hence, is also not responsible for releasing it. Here's the Apple article detailing it. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassFactoryMethods/ClassFactoryMethods.html

Comment: @EdwardL. No, your suggestion that you shouldn't use factory methods is simply not correct. That article you reference is from a doc that predates ARC and is simply saying that if you create an autorelease object from a factory method that you shouldn't manually `release` it, but rather it will be released when the pool is drained. But if you wrap it in an autorelease pool, everything is fine. The problem here is that the autorelease object isn't be created inside the pool, but rather instantiated _before_ the custom pool is created, precisely as rmaddy describes in his answer below (+1).

Comment: @Rob, while I admit that my first suggestion was not his problem. In my second comment, I stated that I'm simply pointing out the difference between the two instantiations and that still holds true regardless of whether or not the article predates ARC. I'm aware that it wasn't necessarily his problem. Hence, why I didn't write it as an answer, but rather as a comment (+1 for rmaddy's answer).

Comment: Very good. If your point is merely that class convenience methods create autorelease objects, whereas `alloc`/`init` objects don't, then I agree with you (as would rmaddy, I suspect, on the basis of his comment above). I just think both of your comments above suggest something more than that, which is the only reason I chimed in. I didn't mean to make a mountain of a mole hill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The autorelease pool is in the wrong place. You only clean up any autoreleased objects created inside the `@autoreleasepool`. But you create the thousands of temporary `NSString` objects outside of the autorelease pool so those aren't cleaned up until after the call to `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` is done.

Try:

```
for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [Logger customLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
    }
}
```

and remove the `@autoreleasepool` in the `customLog:` method.